# I wanted to parse xml data and process that as mysql query

Tags: python, mysql, xml, python-3.x, xml-parsing

I want to parse an xml.

- Read the data one by one, and
- place the data in mysql query fields, and
- write the resultant reply to a file.

Next it should go to next element and so forth.

I am not able to construct for loop for this.

Please help!!

---

I figured it out

```
for ip in ip_list,uid in uid_list,pwd in pwd_list,port in port_list,query in query_list,file in file_list,dbname in dbname_list:
```

---

Please find the contents of xml below

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<jellydb>
<device>
<ip>127.0.0.1</ip>
<port>1433</port>
<dbname>testdb</dbname>
<uid>gowtham</uid>
<pwd>accessallowed</pwd>
<query>select * from IoT</query>
<file>/var/log/db</file>
</device>

<device>
<ip>20.0.0.1</ip>
<port>1433</port>
<dbname>test1db</dbname>
<uid>rohin</uid>
<pwd>accessdenied</pwd>
<query>select * from IoT where brand = 'BMW'</query>
<file>/var/log/db1</file>
</device>
</jellydb>
```

Python code for parsing below:

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree
import mysql.connector


dom = ElementTree.parse('C:\Users\WELCOME\Desktop\sample.xml')
ip = dom.findall('device/ip')
file = dom.findall('device/file')
port = dom.findall('device/port')
query = dom.findall('device/query')
uid = dom.findall('device/uid')
pwd = dom.findall('device/pwd')
dbname = dom.findall('device/dbname')


ip_list = [t.text for t in ip]
file_list = [t.text for t in file]
port_list = [t.text for t in port]
query_list = [t.text for t in query]
uid_list = [t.text for t in uid]
pwd_list = [t.text for t in pwd]
dbname_list = [t.text for t in dbname]

i = 0
```

mysql section

```
db =mysql.connector.Connect(host=<ip_list[1st element in list]>,port=<port_list[[1st element in list]>,user=<uid_list[[1st element in list]>,password=<pwd_list[[1st element in list]>,database=<db_name[[1st element in list]>)
    #cur = db.cursor()
    #result_log = cur.execute(<query_list[[1st element in list]>)
    #re_file = open(<file_list[[1st element in list]>,wr)
    #<file_list[[1st element in list]>.write(result_log)
```

Comment: "for ip in ip_list,uid in uid_list,pwd in pwd_list,port in port_list,query in query_list,file in file_list,dbname in dbname_list:"

Answer (score 0):

Consider a zip loop across all lists assuming equal lengths, appending result iteratively to log file:

```
cur = db.cursor()
strSQL = "INSERT INTO myTable (`IP`, `File`, `Port`, `Query`, `UID`, `PWD`, `DBname`) " + \
          "VALUES(%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s)"

for i,f,pt,q,u,pw,d in zip(ip_list, file_list, port_list, query_list, uid_list, pwd_list, dbname_list):
    result_log = cur.execute(strSQL, (i,f,pt,q,u,pw,d))
    with open('ResultLog.txt', 'a') as f:   # APPEND MODE
       f.write(result_log)
```

Or use [`executemany`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-executemany.html) from list of tuples:

```
sqltuples = [(i,f,pt,q,u,pw,d) for i,f,pt,q,u,pw,d in 
             zip(ip_list, file_list, port_list, query_list, uid_list, pwd_list, dbname_list)]

cur.executemany(strSQL, sqltuples)
```